# UV Mapping Black PNG text on Object

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I have 3 PNG images, one with Red Text,Green text and the other with Black text. I UV unwrap my object, and then apply the images on the mesh. The Red and Green text appears on the mesh, but when I switch to apply the PNG with Black text, it does not appear on my object. Im sure it's there but I cannot see it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If this is black text on transparent background and if you don't use the alpha output to overlay on another color, you will only see black on black, but maybe pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Here's the Packed file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=EYsz5LjP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/EYsz5LjP/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared the black text image, but the red text image that you share has a transparent background, I suppose it is the same for the black text. If you plug the black text in a *Principled BSDF* it will appear entirely black because the alpha channel will be interpreted as black. But if you plug the *Alpha* output into the *Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF* you'll get the transparency (note that in Eevee you'll need to set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend*):

[image]

If you want a colored background, plug the image into a *Color > Mix Color* and use the *Alpha* as factor:

[image]

Comment: The second screen shot with the Mix, is what worked. Keeping the mesh any colour, and the text Black. Thanks!